# New brake pads, whining brakes

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, brake-noise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing noisy V brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/fixing-noisy-v-brakes)

I have quite an old mountain bike, that has become quite rusted over the past few years. I just tuned up the derailleurs and replaced my brake pads.

The front brakes work just fine; no issues. However, the rear brakes whine/squeal very loudly whenever I use them. This happened with my old brake pads and the new ones have caused no change.

What would be the best way to diagnose/fix the noise?

Comment: [This one](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/fixing-noisy-v-brakes) sure solved the problem. Not sure why I didn't search. I feel really dumb right now for not doing that. :P

Comment: No worries! If the problem recurs, we can re-open this. Just edit this with additional info about your bike and the issue, and @reply a modertor here to re-open.